# Tortoise SVN Command Line: Last Time SVN "update" was performed?

Tags: python-3.x, tortoisesvn

I have a PC which is not always connected to the network & where SVN updates must be done manually (when the network connection is available).

I would like to be able to check the last time that an SVN "update" was performed.
I am using Python (I am using the Tortoise SVN command line interface through Python for other tasks).
e.g. If no "update" was performed this week, popup a message to the user to remind them to do it ;)

Ideally, I should be able to do this when there is no network connection & therefore, no connection to SVN.

Is it possible to get this information from any of the SVN command line functions?